# Celery keeps task in memory after finish

Tags: django, memory-leaks, celery

I am using Django with Celery to offload long-running tasks. This all works beautifully, except that when a task is done, Celery seems to keep data in memory.

```
@shared_task
def export_xlsx():
    tmpfile = settings.FILE + ".tmp"
    with open(tmpfile, "w") as datafile:    
        datafile.write(to_xlsx())

    os.rename(settings.FILE + ".tmp", settings.FILE)

    return True
```

the `to_xlsx()` function returns an Excel workbook as string using `save_virtual_workbook` from `openpyxl.writer.excel`:

```
def to_xlsx():
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    col = 1
    row = 1

    articles = models.Article.objects.order_by('articleid')

    for article in articles:
        for articledescription in article.articledescription_set.all():
            ws.cell(row=row, column=1, value=article.articleid)
            ws.cell(row=row, column=3, value=articledescription.description)
            row += 1

    return save_virtual_workbook(wb)
```

And it seems like this string is never released from memory:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                           
26536 bf        20   0 2763256 1.921g   9220 S   0.0 25.0   4:45.69 celery                                                                            
26538 bf        20   0 1550080 798892   7336 R  88.0  9.9   0:08.20 celery
```

PID 26536 is a task that was already finished. 26538 is one that is running.

Comment: FYI, there's a depressing number of results for "celery memory leak" out there...so results of this may vary. This post suggests setting the max tasks per child so that a child will be replaced after it's completed its one task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203016/769971

Comment: @wholevinski I tried some of things already. I also made my task super simple (just `a = ' ' * 1000000000`), and I see it allocates memory, but frees it completely immediately. So I think it does have something to do with my task code.

Comment: Can we see `to_xlsx`? Here's the source for `save_virtual_workbook` and it looks like they're closing all their streams and files properly: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/_modules/openpyxl/writer/excel.html#save_virtual_

Comment: Added `to_xlsx`, I also note that the fewer `ws.cell` calls I do, the less memory leaks.

Comment: So, this won't fix the leak, but using the optimized `write_only` worksheet/cells promises to keep memory usage under 10MB. Could be worth a try to mitigate the issue: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html

Also, did you try the max tasks per child as well? I think combining that + the write only optimized worksheet seems like a pretty reasonable solution without killing yourself trying to find a memory leak in someone else's code.

Comment: That 10MB usage seems to be 10%.